# How to validate same textformfield for different items

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter.
How yo validate same textformfield for different items in a list.
Eg: how to validate quantity field for different items in cart all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `validator` field in TextFormFields for validate content in related TextFormField and then define the key below and set that to a Form Widget, place all TextFormFields in Form Widget. then use global key to validate and then save the contents.

```
// define global key
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

// use this ui widget
      Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value){
                  // validate your content
                }
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value){
                  // validate your content
                }
              ),
              ...
            ],
          ),
      ),

      // use below code for use validate, save
      formKey.currentState.validate()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in my situation same textformfield (quantity) for all list items and validate. example item1 - quantity,  item2 - quantity, item3 - quantity

Comment: validate func in currentState, run validator field in each textFormfield at once, if one validator return false, then validate func return false. I hope I understood your question correctly. If not, give me a better example

Comment: Your above answer worked for me. Also i did saved textformfield with index in temporary local list. Thanks a lot for your help